# i want to print a message by user via discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

i want to print a message by user via bot(discord.py)

means my frd bot working as :

if someone type a message:

?run
print("**hello**")

then bot reply as

**hello**

Answer (score 3):

What you're probably trying to do is bot echo the words that you say, but you have worded it such that you want to execute code on the bot.

If you just want to echo :

```py
@bot.command()
async def echo(ctx, *, words):
    await ctx.reply(words)
```

This would result in :
[image]

If you want to execute code directly from discord to the bot (not recommended) :

```py
@bot.command()
async def run(ctx, *, code):
    # Serious security implications
    exec(code)
```

This is a bad practice and you have to gate this command behind authorized users else anyone could mess with your system, leak your token, and shut down your bot.

Someone could do something like `?run import sys; sys.exit()` and end your bot. So that's bad.